# MySQL - How to order a Select by a specific value in TOP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB which is an Attendance List for a Training Program. In this list - First Subscriptions gets Priority - and LOCAL USERS have priority too.

DB:

```
ID NAME SUBSCRIPTION DATE COUNTRY
1  JOHN 2018-04-05 12:00:00 USA
2  MARY 2018-04-05 12:30:00 CANADA
3  CARL 2018-04-05 13:00:00 USA
```

I need a way to order the table like this:

```
ID NAME SUBSCRIPTION DATE COUNTRY
1  JOHN 2018-04-05 12:00:00 USA
3  CARL 2018-04-05 13:00:00 USA
2  MARY 2018-04-05 12:30:00 CANADA
```

CARL is from USA then I need to give priority to him, even Mary makes his subscription early.

any idea?

** IMPORTANT: Country priority changes according to the location of the training. (here the location is "USA", but can be any country)

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM SUBSCRIPTION_TABLE ORDER BY COUNTRY = 'LOCAL_COUNTRY_VAR', SUBSCRIPTION_DATE
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want to order first by being in the USA and then by the date:

In MySQL, you can do:

```
order by (country = 'USA') desc, date
```

Comment: hi Gordon-Linoff! tks! I made a update in my question - and I was trying something like this.. BUT.. without the parentheses.  solved! tks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a separate table with the location and a priority code (integer). Inner join the two and then order by the priority code ascending. USA would have priority 1, CANADA would be 2.